# C++ validating driving licence program

Tags: c++

I have been banging my head against this for about 2 hours so have decided to get a second or more set of eyes on it. if you can help would be greatly appreciated not to bothered if the answer is in c++ or logic just cant see why its not working.
( The issue I am getting is "string subscript out of range" which is occurring during run time ) The program should take in 9 char into a string the first 5 should be numbers and last 4 should be letters.

```
cout<<"please enter in licence number :";
cin>>licence;
while(licence.length()!=9)
{
  cout<<"Sorry please re-enter licence should be 9 characters"<<endl<<"first 5 are numbers last 4 are Letters :";
  cout<<"please enter in licence number :";
  cin>>licence;
  system("CLS");
}
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
  for(int j=4;j<=9;j++)
  {
    while(!isdigit(licence[i])&&!isalpha(licence[j]))
    {
      cout<<"Sorry please re-enter licence should be 9 characters"<<endl<<"first 5 are numbers last 4 are Letters :";
      cout<<"please enter in licence number :";
      cin>>licence;
      system("CLS");
    }
  }
}
```

Ok so this is my updated function but still not working correctly

```
bool islicensevalid(string license)
{
   if (license.length() != 9) 
   {
     cout<<"Not nine characters long "<<endl;
     return false;
   }

   for (unsigned short index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
   { 
      if(!isdigit(license[index]))
      {
        cout<<"first 5 characters aren't numbers"<<endl;
        return false;
      }
   }

   for (unsigned short index = 5; index < 9; ++index)
   {    
       if(!isalpha(license[index]))
       {
          cout<<"final 4 characters aren't letters"<<endl;
          return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Again I have changed the numbers but it either has the same error as before or it says the last 4 digits are letters

Comment: Your program flow is really horrible. Why are you checking if the 4th character is both a digit and a number? And why are the two tests (for digits and numbers) nested inside one another? And you don't break out of the loop when asking for a new number; you just continue testing where you left off. And after inputting, you don't check the length again.

Comment: The characters from index 4-8 will be checked 4 times each....

Comment: Thanks guys I like the idea of the function much more flexible

Comment: why hasn't anyone suggested using [regexes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) for the task, as those are naturally fitting the validation task?

Comment: You still have a (now clearer) issue of counting license[4] as something that should be a letter, when it should be a number (0,1,2,3,4 are the first 5 entries, and 5,6,7,8 are the last 4 entries).

Comment: still not working.... changed the numbers around it either give out of bounds error or says the last 4 arent letters

Comment: That is because you changed the code from Joe's answer, where it said `i < 9`, to `index < 10`.

Comment: yeah already had that still give me the original error of "string subscript out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break your validation logic out to a separate validation function, as your input and validation logic are too intertwined, leading to your issue.  In particular, if you discover a license is invalid in your validation loop, you aren't checking that the new license entered is the correct length, and you also restart the validation in the middle.  That's not good.

Best to just separate the concerns.  Put the validation logic in one function, and have the input loop call it.  That will make everything much clearer and easier to get correct.

```
bool is_valid_license(const string &license)
{
    // Correct length?
    if (license.length() != 9)
        return false;

    // Are first five characters digits?
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (!isdigit(license[i]))
             return false;

    // Are next four characters letters?
    for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++)
        if (!isalpha(license[i]))
             return false;

    // Valid license
    return true;
}
```

Then in your input code, you can do this:

```
cout << "Please enter in licence number :";
cin >> licence;

while (! is_valid_license(license) )
{
    cout<<"Sorry please re-enter licence should be 9 characters"<<endl<<"first 5 are numbers last 4 are Letters :";
    cout<<"please enter in licence number :";
    cin>>licence;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response just tried still gives same error I tried messing around with the numbers like using 8 etc but nothing

Comment: @user3127943 : I just edited my answer with much more useful detail.

Answer (score 1):

Index 9 is out of range, i.e. the inner loop test should be `j < 9` which you're hitting on the final iteration of the last loop.

I also think you need to initialise `j` at 5 instead of 4, so you only test `licence[5]`, `licence[6]`, `licence[7]` and `licence[8]`.

At present, on your final iteration of the outer loop, you're testing `effectively doing this:

```
while(!isdigit(licence[4])&&!isalpha(licence[4]))
```

Which should always evaluate to `true`.

So to summarise, you should have

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) //outer
```

and

```
for(int j=5;j<9;j++) //inner
```

The outer loop change is actually my personal preference and I find it far more common than using the `i <= MAX-1` style.

Edited to add:
I notice you stop checking the length once the user enters a single string with 9 characters, there's nothing to stop them entering an invalid string of 9 characters followed by 8 characters, which would cause problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Here, among other things, you're reading INSIDE the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    for(int j=4;j<=9;j++)
    {
        while(!isdigit(licence[i])&&!isalpha(licence[j]))
        {
            cout<<"Sorry please re-enter licence should be 9 characters"<<endl<<"first 5 are numbers last 4 are Letters :";
            cout<<"please enter in licence number :";
            cin>>licence;
            system("CLS");
        }
    }
}
```

So if there is an error on 4th digit, you read from input.
What will happen if the license entered is only 3 digit long ? As you will continue your iterator from where you left, the string access in the `while` condition will make this crash.

And why did you intricate the for loops ? They have no relation.

Basically, you should do something like:

```
std::string license;
do
{
  cout<<"please enter in licence number :";
  cin >> license;
}
while (!is_license_valid(license));
```

Where `is_license_valid` is the function doing the verification that will print the error message and return on the first error:

```
bool is_license_valid(const std::string& license)
{
   if (license.length() != 9) 
   {
     // print error
     return false;
   }

   for (unsigned long index = 0; index < 4; ++index)
   { 
      // If not digit print error and return false
   }

   for (unsigned long index = 4; index < 9; ++index)
   { 
      // If not alpha print error and return false
   }

   // all tests passed !
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `unsigned long` overkill for a number in the range 0..9?

Comment: Ive just updated my code to function using your logic but still not working its giving me the second error ive tried changing the index targets a bit but still no luck any idea ?

Comment: @user3127943 Print the offending character, it will help you debug.